# how to reset the elements in a UserControl shown as popup?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a `UserControl` which is shown in a `popup`. I have a button in `usercontrol` that on clicking, makes a `textfield` visible. But as again i visit that `usercontrol`, the `textfiled` remains visible, i want it to be again collapsed until user clicks the `button`.

I have no clue how to do that? which method to override. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `UserControl.Loaded` event to set your textfield to collapsed.

This [blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx) about the Loaded and Initialized Event was very helpful for me.

Example:

UserControl XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespaceName.YourClassName"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="YourClassName_OnLoaded"> 
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="testTextBlock" Text="Invisible on startup" />
        <Button x:Name="testButton" Content="Click" Click="TestButton_OnClick" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl CodeBehind

```
private void YourClassName_OnLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.testTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private void TestButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.testTextBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```